# Making lldb work inside lxc

Tags: llvm, lldb, lxc

I wanted to play with the new lldb since it is supposed to work better on linux and I tried to use it inside a container.

Sadly it seems to consider the connection coming from the container ipv4 and not localhost so it rejects it:

```
error: rejecting incoming connection from 192.168.1.2 (expecting 127.0.0.1)
```

I couldn't see how to make it work so far.

Answer (score 0):

Work on lldb on Linux is ongoing, please file a bug about this at the lldb.llvm.org bugzilla.